# TCP Connection issue Connection refused

Tags: wcf, tcp, performancecounter, nettcpbinding, throttling

even if I am having a huge value of ListenBackLog=10000 and MaxConnection=10000 then also I am getting "tcp error code 10061 target machine actively refused". Its not every time but when load increases then error start appearing and one service is not able to communicate with other.

Following are the other values,

```
ListenBacklog = 10000;

MaxBufferPoolSize = 500000;

MaxBufferSize = 2000000000;

MaxConnections = 10000;

MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2000000000;
```

We already have MaxConcurrentCalls,MaxConcurrentSessions and MaxConcurrentInstances set as 10000.

In normal condition its working fine but when load increases services are not able to communicate with each other.

If we observer the performance counter then Calls Outstanding is lies between 150 to 250. Services are hosted as windows service.

any suggestion or thoughts?

Comment: I assume you use net.tcp, right? Are you using net.tcp port sharing? Because in this case the port sharing service defines listen backlog length, I think.

Comment: Yes we are using net.tcp. No we are not using net.tcp port sharing, individual services have individual port and hence the limit apply to all these separately.